# Entity relationship diagrams in database?

Tags: database

What is the difference between composite attribute and derived attribute in entity relationship diagrams?  Are they the same?

Comment: You ask about multiple things. If you don't know what they are, why are you asking for the difference between them?--Find out what each is. If you think you know what they are, why don't you know "the difference"--and what does that even mean?--Give *definitions* & you tell us what the similarities & differences are or say why there are none. Either way ask a question specifically about how you are stuck on a specific point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Composite attributes** are those that are completely defined by values of two or more attributes For example, Address of a person can be composite of attributes more or less like House number, Street, Town, City, State, Country. Consider the link [Composite Attributes](http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~rmcfadye/2914/hypergraph/composite.html).

Whereas, **Derived attribute** is the one whose value is calculated from other attributes, for example, age of a person can be derived from attribute "Birth date". Consider the link [Derived Attributes](http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~rmcfadye/2914/hypergraph/derived.html)

The Diagrams in the links may help you understand the concept and difference.

Answer (score 1):

a **composite attribute** is an attribute where the attribute **can be broken down further**, such as an address can be further broken down to the number, street and town.
a **derived attribute** is an attribute which doesn't need to be stored separately because it can be **calculated using another attribute**. For example ther is no need to store a persons age again in the data base because once you have the date of birth it can be calculated. On another matter, the age needs to be updated frequently where as the date of birth doesn't.